# SWT eclipse browser does not work on Linux

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt

I have tried eclipse GIT sample to open SWT browser
Ref : http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet260.java
This code works on Windows without any problem .But I get below exception in Linux.

I am developing an eclipse plugin which has repository setting page which is created by extending "AbstractRepositorySettingsPage" in the overrided method @Override "public void run(IProgressMonitor a_monitor) throws CoreException" I am creating Display in this method

**Update :**
This code works if I run it through main() method in Linux.

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: Not implemented [multiple displays]
Root exception:
    org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: Not implemented [multiple displays]
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4423)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.checkDisplay(Display.java:767)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.create(Display.java:908)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<init>(Device.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:507)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:498)
    at com.test$OpenPage.run(test.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui.wizards.AbstractRepositorySettingsPage$29.run(AbstractRepositorySettingsPage.java:1964)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
```

AFAIK above exception is caused because it tries to create a new Display object So I tried to create the Display with existing NON UI thread and open the browser

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable() 
            {
                public void run() 
                {
                   Shell aShell = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getShell();
                    Shell myShell = new Shell (aShell , SWT.SHELL_TRIM);
                    // Very important, generally parents must have a layout set to display children
                    myShell.setLayout (new FillLayout()); 
                    Browser browser = new Browser (myShell, SWT.NONE);
                    browser.setUrl ("http://www.google.de");
                    myShell.layout();
                    myShell.open();
                }
            });
```

The above snippet opens the browser but it does not allow to enter anything in the opened search engine. I want to enter in the available text box and also It does not close the opened browser on click of close button. I terminate the eclipse.

Comment: Where do you create the second `Display`?

Comment: I am developing an eclipse plugin which has repository setting page which is created by extending "AbstractRepositorySettingsPage" in the overrided method @Override
"public void run(IProgressMonitor a_monitor) throws CoreException" I am creating Display in this method

Comment: Ok, but why do you create a new `Display` and not just use the one you can get from the workbench?

Comment: In the above code snippet it creates the display by using existing active workbench.

Comment: The code you posted isn't creating a `Display` at all. You're creating a new `Shell`. Big difference. However, the exception indicates that you're creating a second `Display` somewhere in `com.test$OpenPage.run()`.

Comment: I'm currently working on porting webkit1 to webkit2 on Linux (SWT's Browser). Once done, I will also try to investigate this issue. It might take a while before I get to it thou..